# Feasibility of using Falcon/Falcoder/Llama2 LLM while trying to use it on AWS EC2 Inferentia 2.8xlarge and G4dn.8xLarge Instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, large-language-model, llama

Is it possible to do inference on the aforementioned machines as we are facing so many issues in Inf2 with Falcon model?

Context:

We are facing issues while using Falcon/Falcoder on the Inf2.8xl machine. We were able to run the same experiment on G5.8xl instance successfully but we are observing that the same code is not working on Inf2 machine instance. We are aware that it has Accelerator instead of NVIDIA GPU. Hence we tried its neuron-core's capability and added required helper code for leveraging this capability by using the torch-neuronx library. The code changes and respective error screenshots are provided below for your reference:

Code without any torch-neuronx usage - Generation code snippet:

```
generation_output = model.generate(
input_ids = input_ids,
attention_mask = attention_mask,
generation_config = generation_config,
return_dict_in_generate = True,
output_scores = False,
max_new_tokens = max_new_tokens,
early_stopping = True
)
#print("generation_output")
#print(generation_output)
s = generation_output.sequences[0]
output = tokenizer.decode(s)
```

[Error stack trace - without any torch-neuronx usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOcOC.png)

Code using torch-neuronx - helper function code snippet:

```
def generate_sample_inputs(tokenizer, sequence_length):
    dummy_input = "dummy"
    embeddings = tokenizer(dummy_input, max_length=sequence_length,     
                           padding="max_length",return_tensors="pt")
    return tuple(embeddings.values())
```

```
def compile_model_inf2(model, tokenizer, sequence_length, num_neuron_cores):
    #use only one neuron core
    os.environ["NEURON_RT_NUM_CORES"] = str(num_neuron_cores)
    import torch_neuronx
    payload = generate_sample_inputs(tokenizer, sequence_length)
    return torch_neuronx.trace(model, payload)
```

```
model = compile_model_inf2(model, tokenizer, sequence_length=512, num_neuron_cores=1)
```

[Stack trace using torch-neuronx1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os3o1.png)

[Stack trace using torch-neuronx2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QkO4.png)

Can this github issue address our specific problems mentioned above?

https://github.com/oobabooga/text-generation-webui/issues/2260

So basically my query is:

Is it feasible to do inference with Llama 2/Falcon model on G4dn.8xLarge/ Inferentia 2.8xlarge instances or they are not supported yet? If not, which machine instance we should try considering cost-effectiveness?

**Code without any torch-neuronx usage - Generation code snippet:
**

```
generation_output = model.generate(
input_ids = input_ids,
attention_mask = attention_mask,
generation_config = generation_config,
return_dict_in_generate = True,
output_scores = False,
max_new_tokens = max_new_tokens,
early_stopping = True
)
#print("generation_output")
#print(generation_output)
s = generation_output.sequences[0]
output = tokenizer.decode(s)
```

**Code using torch-neuronx - helper function code snippet:
**

```
def generate_sample_inputs(tokenizer, sequence_length):
    dummy_input = "dummy"
    embeddings = tokenizer(dummy_input, max_length=sequence_length,  
                           padding="max_length",return_tensors="pt")
    return tuple(embeddings.values())
```

```
def compile_model_inf2(model, tokenizer, sequence_length, num_neuron_cores):
    #use only one neuron core
    os.environ["NEURON_RT_NUM_CORES"] = str(num_neuron_cores)
    import torch_neuronx
    payload = generate_sample_inputs(tokenizer, sequence_length)
    return torch_neuronx.trace(model, payload)
```

```
model = compile_model_inf2(model, tokenizer, sequence_length=512, num_neuron_cores=1)
```

The error stack traces are shared already.

Comment: I'd be very interested in what you ended up doing and also in any cost estimates.